# Changing a FrameLayout to a CardView (following online tutorial)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have tried to change my framelayout to a CardView using the following tutorial, https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-CardView.

Originally I had the code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/note_tile_margin">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tile_clickable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/tile_padding"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_tile_expand"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="@integer/max_tile_lines"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Write your message here... "
                android:textColor="@color/tile_text" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_expand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/click_selector"
                android:gravity="top" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_tile_menu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_expand" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tile_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_links"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="Hyperlinks"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_web" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_delete"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/deleteNote"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_delete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_share"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/share"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_share" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_copy"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="Copy to clipboard"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_copy" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

then I followed the steps outlined in this tutorial and changed the bits it told me to. It seemed to be quite easy to follow the steps and the code is now,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tile_clickable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/tile_padding"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_tile_expand"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="@integer/max_tile_lines"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Write your message here... "
                android:textColor="@color/tile_text" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_expand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/click_selector"
                android:gravity="top" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_tile_menu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_expand" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tile_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_links"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="Hyperlinks"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_web" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_delete"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/deleteNote"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_delete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_share"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/share"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_share" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_tile_copy"
                style="@style/btn_tile_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="Copy to clipboard"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dark_copy" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I then go to build the project and get the following error message:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I implement this CardView layout properly and what is going wrong?

Note: This is linked to my last problem, [Rounding the corners of views in notepad android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956207/rounded-the-corners-of-views-in-notepad-android-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed quotation mark in layout_height="wrap_content":

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: thanks for noticing that, i have changed it but there is still a probelm. Im going to have to rewrite this question, to add the error now

Comment: I have now edited the question so that it is the correct question I want to ask. Apologies.

Comment: Did you add this to you app gradle? 
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'